# Checking if file exists in ksh

Tags: shell, ksh

In the ksh manual under tests, there are the `-a` and the `-e` flags which check if the file exists.  I was wondering if there are any differences between them, and if so, which one is preferable under which situations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The situation depends on what you are looking for.  These flags will interest you:

```
a  -- not really a file test:  it's the "and" conjunction.
d  -- it is a directory
e  -- it exists 
f  -- it is an ordinary file
s  -- it exists and non-zero size
```

You want to search  **UNIX manual test**  for thorough list.  and by all means practice on different files and directories.

Answer (score 1):

Both -a and -e are defined as tests for the existence of a file, and are identical in function.  In my experience, -f is used most of the time, as coders need to test not only existence, but also file type.